# What is the relation between Levenshtein Word Distance and Boyer Moore searching algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, levenshtein-distance, boyer-moore

Would they both be considered string matching algorithms?

Say I want to detect how close two strings are, so I want to match them. Thus I would use the  Levenshtein Word Distance. However, if the strings are entire sentences, maybe first i should use the search algorithm or is it an overkill? Do these two algorithms complement each other? It seems to me there is some overlap in the use between them, but i cannot explain what it might be. Therefore i am asking what is the relation between the two if any?

Yes, this is pretty much a noob question.

Comment: Not really, IMO. B-M is for searching a (large) body of text for a string. Lev is more about detecting similarities (or differences, if you prefer) between two strings.

Comment: I think this is a great question and one I am also looking for answers to. If I had to implement a string search algorithm, I would first generate a kind of lookup table sorted by Levenshtein distances to the input, then run the Boyer-Moore algorithm on each table entry.